# WampServer re direcciona todos los proyectos al LOCALHOST

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, wampserver

Estoy trabajando con WAMPSERVER versión 3.2.3 - 64bit y desde hace un par de días todo proyecto que ejecuto solo me abre el Localhost, no me corre ningún proyecto todos cuando los ejecuto solo abren esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Leíste el mensaje debajo de "Tus proyectos"? Dice que debes crear un host virtual para cada carpeta. Aunque puedes hacer clic derecho en el icono de Wampserver (en la barra de tareas), seleccionar "Wamp settings" y "Add localhost in url"

Comment: Lo intente pero no tiene la opcion de Add localhost in url

Comment: Intenta hacerlo de forma manual, edita el archivo `c:\wamp64\wampmanager.conf` busca la variable `urlAddLocalhost = "on"` y asegúrate de que esté en "on". Yo tengo la versión 3.1.7, pero ahí debería seguir la opción.